# Ansible Automation Hub LDAP authentication/login

Tags: ldap, ansible-2.x, ansible-awx

I'm using Ansible Automation Platform 2.2.1 and managed to configure LDAP for Automation Controller (on server A) so that one can sign in using AD credentials.

I'd like to do the same for Automation Hub on a different server (server B).

In my inventory file on Automation Controller server (A) I set the values for Automation Hub analogous to Automation Controller eg. automationhub_authentication_backend, automationhub_ldap_server_uri etc.

But I don't see any LDAP connection attempts neither on server A nor on server B  when I try to signin on Automation Hub.

With the local admin user login to Automation Hub works.

What am I missing?
Where is the log file for Automation Hub stored?

Answer (score 0):

The log is stored in /var/log/messages

The LDAP settings should be set in /etc/pulp/settings.py and the webserver has to be restarted to take the new value.

In my case I had to set the variable from

```
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE_CLASS = 'django_auth_ldap.config:GroupOfNamesType'
```

to

```
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE_CLASS = 'django_auth_ldap.config:ActiveDirectoryGroupType'
```

to get login with AD credentials working.